# Apexcharts - hover on a very small column

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts, apexcharts

I have a situation while using `apexcharts` when one of the columns is very small. Its difficult to render the tooltip because you have to be very careful to hover the column.

**Question**: is there a way to extend the hover area so its easier to hover the column? Or maybe theres an option to render the tooltip when hovering the whole vertical area (the space over and below the column)? Thank you!

> Playground with problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-forked-nw3ll?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution I have that seems to work is to set tooltip 'shared' to 'true':

```
tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      shared: true, 
    },
```

By doing this, the tooltip will show above each column [solution video](https://media.giphy.com/media/atsC8sL1RxhWUgAMsv/giphy.gif)

[codesandbox solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-forked-osnds?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks but its still very hard to hover the small column, doesnt work :(

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking for.  Can you look at the solution video I just included in the answer and tell me if this is not what you're looking for?

Comment: I wish I had 15 rep to upvote this. It works like a charm, thank you!!!

Comment: @underfrankenwood You have 15 rep now, upvote :-)